Do these notes belong to the same scale, and, if not, why don't they seem dissonant?
I was watching the notes of a song I like, and I found this:

I don't know much if anything about music theory, but in most scales I have used, most 3-note chords can't include a note next to one of the chord notes and still sound alright. But in this case it sounds pretty cool. Why is that? Is there a scale that allows this? If so, what's the name of that scale?

Sorry, can't even understand what the diagram is saying!

@Tim I think it's just "piano-roll"; a CM chord followed by a D/A, but the melody includes an F# during the C measure and an E and G during the D measure.

To Pablo: The short answer is yes, what's going on here is perfectly common. The long answer is difficult because there are so many misunderstandings. If nobody beats me to it I'll take a crack at it later, but it involves the differences between chords, keys ("scales"), and melodies.


... in most scales I have used, most 3-note chords can't include a note next to one of the chord notes and still sound alright.

First, there's some truth to what you're saying. It's true that, if we play two notes that are right next to each other, we usually perceive that as a dissonance. And it's true that the simplest kinds of chords (three-note, or "triadic" chords) include spaces between their notes so we don't get this dissonance.
But how "alright" is "alright"? The first thing that isn't true is "we can never use dissonance." The "clash" of those neighboring notes might be an unpleasant sensation, but it's a sensation, and it's not boring! So putting dissonances in clever places can be a way to "spice up" music. Eating a hot pepper by itself might not be fun, but using it in the right amount with other ingredients can make a dish more interesting.
So depending on what music we're trying to make, it could often be okay to include neighboring notes even in a three-note chord. Walk up to a piano and play an F# and a G—there's that dissonance. But then, along with them, play a D or a B below them: these added "ingredients" help blend the "flavors" and we get a chord that is not unpleasant. (If you're doing specific composition exercises, "counterpoint," then this sort of thing might be against the rules, but it's certainly not against any universal rule that applies to all music.)
But that's not even what's going on here. Another thing that's not true is "All the notes you here are parts of a chord." Even if they all happen at the same time. At the start of your image, we have C, E, F#, and G. But the F# is much shorter than the others. The C, E, and G last for 4 beats. This is a simple C major chord. After them we have A, D, and F#; that's a simple D chord (though with an A as the bottom note). Those are the real chords; the light green notes are then added on top of them, and move around within them. This happens often in music; we have some notes that are "harmony" or a chordal structure, and some notes that are "melody," which make a line from note to note. There's no rule that these notes have to use only notes that belong to the chord (or even to the "scale"/key!). It's true that the F# creates a dissonance against the G, but it doesn't last long, and we overlook it as it "resolves" into an E.

Is there a scale that allows this?

Scales don't make rules! Certain types of genres or compositional practices might make rules; counterpoint has lots of rules. But in general modern musical practice, you can structure your music around a set of notes (you might call it a "scale," or maybe better a "key"), but you can also include notes from outside that set, as long as you use them in a way that makes sense. Also, most of the most-common scales do include notes that are "right next to each other" (i.e. have an interval of a half step). Those intervals are in the usual major and minor scales, and in most of the less common "modal" scales. Playing two notes that are a half-step apart together, at once, doesn't really say anything about which scale you're in; it just says that you have a good compositional reason for using those two notes of the scale.
There aren't really enough notes here to say for sure what key we're in, but it looks like D major.

“Scales don't make rules!” — That's probably worth emboldening!  (And maybe putting in huge, bright red letters, to judge from the number of questions that seem to assume so…)

More context is needed to give a complete answer, but what you seem to be showing us is essentially a C major chord in root position followed by a D major chord in 2nd inversion.
Each of the two chords is then accompanied by notes extraneous to it, at least one of which could be interpreted as a grace note (the first F#), while the others—and perhaps all of them—are part of the actual melody.
One context this would be consistent with is a piece in the key (“scale” if you want) of G major, making the first chord the subdominant and the second one the dominant of that key.
The reason why you don't sense any dissonance is because all of the notes that don't belong to the chords are played in a way that resolves any “conflict“ between the notes almost immediately (the F# at the beginning “dissolves” into the G, while the E and the G near the end can be construed as so-called passing notes).

There is a C major chord followed by a D major chord. Pitches present are G A ... C D E F#. The missing B, if it appears, would most likely be natural. That could be a key signature of one sharp. The scales could be G major or E minor. You need more context to say more.

...most 3-note chords can't include a note next to one of the chord notes...

That's true for basic triads, and therefore those tones are called non-chord tones. Such non-chord tones are usually melodic motion. Technically those tones are dissonant, but dissonance should not be thought of a simply "sounding bad." Dissonance creates tension and that tension lends itself to expressiveness and through the interplay of tension and resolution provides forward motion to music. Dissonance "sounds good" when it is handled skillfully.
